# Rails: Using JQuery to display results of a form submit button calling another page?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've got my first Rails application working! I have a text-field for a user to enter a sentence, and then from that sentence, I use:

```
form_tag(another_page, :method => "get")
```

to send the text-field value into another page, which calls a class I made and plays around with the sentence structure.

Now, I want to take it one step further! I want to be able to use JQuery (maybe the .load command?) to display the results on the same page, without having to load a completely separate page. (I'm going to eventually make it so each new sentence is pushed down one (using .prepend) and the newer sentence appear at the top.)

My two questions are: Is this an acceptable way of doing it (using JQuery to load the contents of another page)? And, most importantly, how do I modify my code to do this?

I'm familiar with some JQuery, but I don't know how to, for example, change the form submission in Rails to not load a new page (and instead get that new page in a JQuery.load call).

Thanks,
Derek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derek, welcome to Rails!

First of all, yes using jQuery is a great idea.

There are a few ways to do it. You can write straight jQuery and in an external javascript file call (or something like this):

```
$('#form_id').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: $this.attr('action'),
    type: $this.attr('method').toUpperCase(),
    data: $this.serialize(),
    success: function(data) { /* Do Stuff */ }
  })
});
```

Or rails has some helpers that do some of this for you so that all you have to do is say `form_tag(another_page, :method => "get", :remote => true)`. For this you do need to include the `rails.js` file on your page as well (here's a good article on it : http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/)

Does that help?

Comment: Don't forget to include the jquery-ujs gem otherwise it will use prototype instead https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

Comment: Yes, this help. Thank you! I might go the way for rails.js, looks easier to me.

Comment: Go for it. It is probably easier, esp. for what you've mentioned. Would you mind confirming my answer?